# Why escape character & quote character cannot be set to null in PolyBase copy method in ADF if we are not doing Staging?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-analytics

I am copying data from azure data lake gen 2 to azure synapse via an ADF copy activity using PolyBase.
When I run the pipeline it gives the following validation outputs. I don't want to do 'Staging'. But If I enable Staging then these outputs disappear.
Also if  I set the value of **Quote character: No quote character & Escape character: No escape character** then also this source format validation goes away.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#use-polybase-to-load-data-into-azure-synapse-analytics), `quoteChar` and `escapeChar` are not specified in the PolyBase copy method, as shown below:

[image]

This could be why the source format validation goes away when the values of **Quote character: No quote character & Escape character: No escape character** are set, as illustrated below:

[image]

However, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#staged-copy), when you activate the staging feature, data is first copied from the source data store to the staging storage. Then, the data is copied from the staging to the sink data store. Data transformations or validations might occur during this staging process, and any issues related to source format might be resolved, which is why the validation errors disappear when you enable staging.

The difference can be seen as follows:
When staging is enabled in the PolyBase method, the copied data appears as shown below:

[image]

However, when the stagging feature is disabled and the values of Quote character: No quote character & Escape character: No escape character are set in the PolyBase method, the copied data does not match the source, and there may be changes in the data, as shown below:

[image]